Can I unmount my data drive without losing data?
I messed up my system and need to wipe my system (see here: Can't use sudo anymore since running chmod: sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable)
Fortunately even though I am a beginner, I have one drive for the system, and one 12TB drive for my data.
These are the specs:

Operating System: Ubuntu Server 24.04
Architecture: x64
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-3450 CPU
RAM: 8GB
Storage:
SSD > 128GB (system drive)
|| HDD > 12TB (used as nasdrive)

I use this as my Home-Server with plenty of self-hosted applications. If the data of the 12TB drive would be lost I would lose it with all the data that needs to be recovered. I mounted the 12TB drive to ~/mnt/nasdrive/. From my understanding, I could theoretically unmount the 12TB drive, and keep the data that is on it right now, wipe the system, install the fresh system, mount the 12TB drive again and go on as if nothing ever happened correct?
I could use sudo umount <device|directory> so basically sudo umount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/nasdrive
Problem is I messed up my system and can't use sudo anymore, so I'm not sure if I can even unmount the drive. Is there any other solution than to use sudo unmount that doesn't require sudo or to just manually remove the drive from the system and hoping the data is not lost?

You could boot from the install media USB and see if the drive is OK.

The drive is automatically unmounted when you shut down your system. Booting your installer will not automatically mount any drive, you just need to take care that you install your OS to the correct drive and not accidentally to your data drive. Is this data drive installed in your computer or is it installed in a different device and you access it over your LAN?

It's mounted on the same device, meaning inside of the same computer. So that would mean I wouldn't even have to unmount my drive correct? I could just shutdown the computer manually (not ideal but the only way i guess) and reinstall the os without touching the drive since ill just wipe and reinstall the os on the drive with the system on it?

If at all possible find some way of making a copy of your data.  I can't think of any reason for having a single copy of important digital  information more than a few days old.
